# Automated line break in css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm adding multiple authors on a WordPress blog: www.denfri.dk

When more than 3 authors are added, the byline breaks the grid on the front page.

Example: www.denfri.dk/page/3/ the post called 'test'

What do I need to add to my stylesheet in order to make the list of authors jump to the next line, when the first line has run out of space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the width of the .byline_loop to 283px

```
.byline_loop {
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    max-width: 283px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

So if the text is longer than 283px it will go onto the next line. Also 283px is the width of the image.

Comment: Thanks! I used max-width instead, so elements that aren't maxed out won't always fill max width. Thanks for sending me down the right path!

Comment: No problem, I changed it to max width.